# Bolding Numbers in Data Frame

Tags: r, kable, stargazer, kableextra, gt

I have the following dataset (a sample of a large dataset)

```
          VARIABLES         1         2         3         4
            DEGREE                                        
       EIGENVECTOR  0.80***                               
       BETWEENNESS  0.75***   0.64***                     
         CLOSENESS  0.88***   0.90***   0.75***           
 OVERALLCENTRALITY  0.64***   0.55***   0.62***   0.64***
```

I want to **BOLD** the numbers in the data frame that has asterisk and get rid of asterisk from the **BOLDED** numbers.

In this dataset all numbers have asterisk(*), but in main dataset, some numbers have one asterisk, or two asterisks, or three asterisks, or no asterisk. I want to **BOLD** those numbers *if they have at least one asterisk* - meaning that I do not want to **bold** those numbers that *do not have any asterisk*.

My ultimate purpose is to use this dataset in `stargazer` function to product a latex output in pdf.

full data here-

```
dput(df)

structure(list(VARIABLES = c("DEGREE", "EIGENVECTOR", "BETWEENNESS", 
"CLOSENESS", "OVERALLCENTRALITY", "LNASSETS", "LEVERAGE", "INVREC", 
"LOSS", "ROA", "ZSCORE", "MERGER", "MTB", "FOREIGN", "EXTRAORDINARY", 
"SEGMENT", "SPECIALIZED", "RESTATEMENT", "BIGN", "GOINGCONCERN", 
"CALENDARYEAR", "LNNONAUDFEES", "LNAUDFEES", "AUDTURNOVER", "RESTRUCTURE", 
"LITIGATE", "AGE", "AUDITLAG", "UNQUALIFIED", "MATERIALWEAKNESS", 
"AUDITORTENURE", "LOGEAL", "FILINGLAG", "OPERATINGCFO"), `1` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
EIGENVECTOR = 31L, BETWEENNESS = 30L, CLOSENESS = 32L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 29L, 
LNASSETS = 28L, LEVERAGE = 23L, INVREC = 9L, LOSS = 7L, ROA = 17L, 
ZSCORE = 16L, MERGER = 18L, MTB = 14L, FOREIGN = 21L, EXTRAORDINARY = 13L, 
SEGMENT = 22L, SPECIALIZED = 20L, RESTATEMENT = 4L, BIGN = 26L, 
GOINGCONCERN = 6L, CALENDARYEAR = 15L, LNNONAUDFEES = 25L, LNAUDFEES = 27L, 
AUDTURNOVER = 8L, RESTRUCTURE = 2L, LITIGATE = 5L, AGE = 19L, 
AUDITLAG = 11L, UNQUALIFIED = 3L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 5L, AUDITORTENURE = 24L, 
LOGEAL = 12L, FILINGLAG = 10L, OPERATINGCFO = 17L), .Label = c("", 
"-0.01    ", "-0.03*** ", "-0.04*** ", "-0.06*** ", "-0.09*** ", 
"-0.11*** ", "-0.12*** ", "-0.17*** ", "-0.22*** ", "-0.30*** ", 
"-0.33*** ", " 0.02*** ", " 0.04*** ", " 0.05*** ", " 0.10*** ", 
" 0.11*** ", " 0.12*** ", " 0.15*** ", " 0.16*** ", " 0.17*** ", 
" 0.18*** ", " 0.20*** ", " 0.23*** ", " 0.36*** ", " 0.37*** ", 
" 0.48*** ", " 0.50*** ", " 0.64*** ", " 0.75*** ", " 0.80*** ", 
" 0.88*** "), class = "factor"), `2` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 29L, CLOSENESS = 30L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 28L, 
LNASSETS = 27L, LEVERAGE = 22L, INVREC = 9L, LOSS = 6L, ROA = 16L, 
ZSCORE = 19L, MERGER = 17L, MTB = 14L, FOREIGN = 18L, EXTRAORDINARY = 13L, 
SEGMENT = 20L, SPECIALIZED = 21L, RESTATEMENT = 4L, BIGN = 25L, 
GOINGCONCERN = 5L, CALENDARYEAR = 15L, LNNONAUDFEES = 24L, LNAUDFEES = 26L, 
AUDTURNOVER = 8L, RESTRUCTURE = 2L, LITIGATE = 7L, AGE = 18L, 
AUDITLAG = 12L, UNQUALIFIED = 3L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 4L, AUDITORTENURE = 23L, 
LOGEAL = 11L, FILINGLAG = 10L, OPERATINGCFO = 16L), .Label = c("", 
"-0.01    ", "-0.02*** ", "-0.05*** ", "-0.06*** ", "-0.08*** ", 
"-0.09*** ", "-0.11*** ", "-0.17*** ", "-0.19*** ", "-0.27*** ", 
"-0.28*** ", " 0.01*   ", " 0.02*** ", " 0.04*** ", " 0.06*** ", 
" 0.08*** ", " 0.12*** ", " 0.14*** ", " 0.15*** ", " 0.16*** ", 
" 0.20*** ", " 0.22*** ", " 0.30*** ", " 0.33*** ", " 0.42*** ", 
" 0.43*** ", " 0.55*** ", " 0.64*** ", " 0.90*** "), class = "factor"), 
    `3` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, 
    CLOSENESS = 24L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 23L, LNASSETS = 21L, 
    LEVERAGE = 17L, INVREC = 7L, LOSS = 3L, ROA = 11L, ZSCORE = 15L, 
    MERGER = 14L, MTB = 12L, FOREIGN = 16L, EXTRAORDINARY = 10L, 
    SEGMENT = 16L, SPECIALIZED = 14L, RESTATEMENT = 3L, BIGN = 19L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 4L, CALENDARYEAR = 13L, LNNONAUDFEES = 20L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 22L, AUDTURNOVER = 5L, RESTRUCTURE = 9L, LITIGATE = 3L, 
    AGE = 14L, AUDITLAG = 8L, UNQUALIFIED = 2L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 2L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 18L, LOGEAL = 8L, FILINGLAG = 6L, OPERATINGCFO = 11L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.02*** ", "-0.03*** ", "-0.04*** ", 
    "-0.08*** ", "-0.16*** ", "-0.17*** ", "-0.22*** ", " 0.00    ", 
    " 0.01    ", " 0.02**  ", " 0.03*** ", " 0.05*** ", " 0.10*** ", 
    " 0.13*** ", " 0.15*** ", " 0.19*** ", " 0.20*** ", " 0.28*** ", 
    " 0.30*** ", " 0.37*** ", " 0.38*** ", " 0.62*** ", " 0.75*** "
    ), class = "factor"), `4` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, 
    BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 25L, 
    LNASSETS = 23L, LEVERAGE = 19L, INVREC = 8L, LOSS = 6L, ROA = 12L, 
    ZSCORE = 15L, MERGER = 14L, MTB = 13L, FOREIGN = 18L, EXTRAORDINARY = 11L, 
    SEGMENT = 18L, SPECIALIZED = 17L, RESTATEMENT = 4L, BIGN = 22L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 5L, CALENDARYEAR = 13L, LNNONAUDFEES = 21L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 24L, AUDTURNOVER = 7L, RESTRUCTURE = 2L, LITIGATE = 4L, 
    AGE = 16L, AUDITLAG = 10L, UNQUALIFIED = 3L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 5L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 20L, LOGEAL = 10L, FILINGLAG = 9L, OPERATINGCFO = 12L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01    ", "-0.01**  ", "-0.05*** ", 
    "-0.06*** ", "-0.07*** ", "-0.12*** ", "-0.19*** ", "-0.23*** ", 
    "-0.32*** ", " 0.01    ", " 0.05*** ", " 0.06*** ", " 0.11*** ", 
    " 0.13*** ", " 0.15*** ", " 0.17*** ", " 0.19*** ", " 0.21*** ", 
    " 0.27*** ", " 0.36*** ", " 0.37*** ", " 0.48*** ", " 0.49*** ", 
    " 0.64*** "), class = "factor"), `5` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 26L, LEVERAGE = 22L, INVREC = 9L, LOSS = 3L, ROA = 13L, 
    ZSCORE = 19L, MERGER = 18L, MTB = 16L, FOREIGN = 23L, EXTRAORDINARY = 6L, 
    SEGMENT = 20L, SPECIALIZED = 17L, RESTATEMENT = 7L, BIGN = 24L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 5L, CALENDARYEAR = 15L, LNNONAUDFEES = 25L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 27L, AUDTURNOVER = 8L, RESTRUCTURE = 2L, LITIGATE = 3L, 
    AGE = 21L, AUDITLAG = 12L, UNQUALIFIED = 22L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 4L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 28L, LOGEAL = 10L, FILINGLAG = 11L, OPERATINGCFO = 14L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01    ", "-0.02*** ", "-0.03*** ", 
    "-0.04*** ", "-0.05*** ", "-0.06*** ", "-0.10*** ", "-0.15*** ", 
    "-0.20*** ", "-0.24*** ", "-0.33*** ", " 0.02**  ", " 0.02*** ", 
    " 0.05*** ", " 0.06*** ", " 0.07*** ", " 0.09*** ", " 0.12*** ", 
    " 0.13*** ", " 0.16*** ", " 0.18*** ", " 0.19*** ", " 0.20*** ", 
    " 0.27*** ", " 0.39*** ", " 0.40*** ", " 0.42*** "), class = "factor"), 
    `6` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, 
    CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 23L, 
    INVREC = 7L, LOSS = 11L, ROA = 23L, ZSCORE = 17L, MERGER = 18L, 
    MTB = 3L, FOREIGN = 19L, EXTRAORDINARY = 15L, SEGMENT = 22L, 
    SPECIALIZED = 20L, RESTATEMENT = 4L, BIGN = 25L, GOINGCONCERN = 9L, 
    CALENDARYEAR = 16L, LNNONAUDFEES = 26L, LNAUDFEES = 27L, 
    AUDTURNOVER = 8L, RESTRUCTURE = 2L, LITIGATE = 10L, AGE = 21L, 
    AUDITLAG = 13L, UNQUALIFIED = 5L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 6L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 24L, LOGEAL = 14L, FILINGLAG = 12L, OPERATINGCFO = 22L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01    ", "-0.02*** ", "-0.04*** ", 
    "-0.06*** ", "-0.07*** ", "-0.11*** ", "-0.17*** ", "-0.20*** ", 
    "-0.22*** ", "-0.33*** ", "-0.35*** ", "-0.48*** ", "-0.54*** ", 
    " 0.06*** ", " 0.12*** ", " 0.16*** ", " 0.22*** ", " 0.23*** ", 
    " 0.24*** ", " 0.30*** ", " 0.34*** ", " 0.35*** ", " 0.37*** ", 
    " 0.55*** ", " 0.63*** ", " 0.84*** "), class = "factor"), 
    `7` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, 
    CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, 
    INVREC = 11L, LOSS = 14L, ROA = 10L, ZSCORE = 22L, MERGER = 12L, 
    MTB = 4L, FOREIGN = 3L, EXTRAORDINARY = 13L, SEGMENT = 15L, 
    SPECIALIZED = 16L, RESTATEMENT = 2L, BIGN = 19L, GOINGCONCERN = 19L, 
    CALENDARYEAR = 18L, LNNONAUDFEES = 20L, LNAUDFEES = 21L, 
    AUDTURNOVER = 5L, RESTRUCTURE = 11L, LITIGATE = 9L, AGE = 15L, 
    AUDITLAG = 7L, UNQUALIFIED = 7L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 12L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 17L, LOGEAL = 6L, FILINGLAG = 5L, OPERATINGCFO = 8L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01    ", "-0.01*   ", "-0.04*** ", 
    "-0.05*** ", "-0.06*** ", "-0.09*** ", "-0.10*** ", "-0.13*** ", 
    "-0.15*** ", " 0.00    ", " 0.02*** ", " 0.04*** ", " 0.05*** ", 
    " 0.07*** ", " 0.09*** ", " 0.10*** ", " 0.14*** ", " 0.18*** ", 
    " 0.24*** ", " 0.34*** ", " 0.49*** "), class = "factor"), 
    `8` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, 
    CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, 
    INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 9L, ROA = 23L, ZSCORE = 12L, MERGER = 17L, 
    MTB = 7L, FOREIGN = 21L, EXTRAORDINARY = 2L, SEGMENT = 22L, 
    SPECIALIZED = 4L, RESTATEMENT = 13L, BIGN = 10L, GOINGCONCERN = 6L, 
    CALENDARYEAR = 11L, LNNONAUDFEES = 5L, LNAUDFEES = 6L, AUDTURNOVER = 16L, 
    RESTRUCTURE = 3L, LITIGATE = 6L, AGE = 20L, AUDITLAG = 19L, 
    UNQUALIFIED = 15L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 17L, AUDITORTENURE = 8L, 
    LOGEAL = 14L, FILINGLAG = 18L, OPERATINGCFO = 19L), .Label = c("", 
    "-0.01    ", "-0.01*   ", "-0.02**  ", "-0.03*** ", "-0.04*** ", 
    "-0.05*** ", "-0.06*** ", "-0.09*** ", "-0.11*** ", "-0.16*** ", 
    "-0.28*** ", " 0.00    ", " 0.02**  ", " 0.02*** ", " 0.04*** ", 
    " 0.05*** ", " 0.06*** ", " 0.09*** ", " 0.10*** ", " 0.12*** ", 
    " 0.13*** ", " 0.15*** "), class = "factor"), `9` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 12L, 
    ZSCORE = 21L, MERGER = 7L, MTB = 13L, FOREIGN = 4L, EXTRAORDINARY = 2L, 
    SEGMENT = 7L, SPECIALIZED = 5L, RESTATEMENT = 13L, BIGN = 8L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 19L, CALENDARYEAR = 14L, LNNONAUDFEES = 10L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 9L, AUDTURNOVER = 15L, RESTRUCTURE = 3L, LITIGATE = 17L, 
    AGE = 10L, AUDITLAG = 20L, UNQUALIFIED = 3L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 16L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 6L, LOGEAL = 22L, FILINGLAG = 18L, OPERATINGCFO = 11L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01*   ", "-0.04*** ", "-0.07*** ", 
    "-0.08*** ", "-0.12*** ", "-0.14*** ", "-0.17*** ", "-0.20*** ", 
    "-0.21*** ", "-0.48*** ", "-0.63*** ", " 0.00    ", " 0.04*** ", 
    " 0.05*** ", " 0.10*** ", " 0.18*** ", " 0.19*** ", " 0.21*** ", 
    " 0.23*** ", " 0.27*** ", " 0.31*** "), class = "factor"), 
    `10` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, 
    CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, 
    INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, ZSCORE = 9L, MERGER = 18L, 
    MTB = 11L, FOREIGN = 17L, EXTRAORDINARY = 12L, SEGMENT = 20L, 
    SPECIALIZED = 15L, RESTATEMENT = 2L, BIGN = 19L, GOINGCONCERN = 10L, 
    CALENDARYEAR = 3L, LNNONAUDFEES = 21L, LNAUDFEES = 22L, AUDTURNOVER = 3L, 
    RESTRUCTURE = 13L, LITIGATE = 6L, AGE = 20L, AUDITLAG = 7L, 
    UNQUALIFIED = 14L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 4L, AUDITORTENURE = 16L, 
    LOGEAL = 8L, FILINGLAG = 5L, OPERATINGCFO = 23L), .Label = c("", 
    "-0.01    ", "-0.06*** ", "-0.07*** ", "-0.18*** ", "-0.20*** ", 
    "-0.23*** ", "-0.32*** ", "-0.36*** ", "-0.41*** ", " 0.00    ", 
    " 0.02**  ", " 0.06*** ", " 0.07*** ", " 0.08*** ", " 0.12*** ", 
    " 0.14*** ", " 0.16*** ", " 0.17*** ", " 0.20*** ", " 0.21*** ", 
    " 0.23*** ", " 0.83*** "), class = "factor"), `11` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 8L, MTB = 9L, FOREIGN = 10L, EXTRAORDINARY = 14L, 
    SEGMENT = 6L, SPECIALIZED = 3L, RESTATEMENT = 13L, BIGN = 2L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 18L, CALENDARYEAR = 20L, LNNONAUDFEES = 15L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 17L, AUDTURNOVER = 12L, RESTRUCTURE = 12L, LITIGATE = 9L, 
    AGE = 7L, AUDITLAG = 17L, UNQUALIFIED = 5L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 15L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 4L, LOGEAL = 19L, FILINGLAG = 16L, OPERATINGCFO = 11L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01    ", "-0.02*** ", "-0.03*** ", 
    "-0.06*** ", "-0.09*** ", "-0.10*** ", "-0.14*** ", "-0.15*** ", 
    "-0.23*** ", "-0.32*** ", " 0.00    ", " 0.01    ", " 0.02*** ", 
    " 0.04*** ", " 0.05*** ", " 0.07*** ", " 0.15*** ", " 0.16*** ", 
    " 0.19*** "), class = "factor"), `12` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 9L, FOREIGN = 17L, EXTRAORDINARY = 8L, 
    SEGMENT = 16L, SPECIALIZED = 10L, RESTATEMENT = 2L, BIGN = 13L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 5L, CALENDARYEAR = 4L, LNNONAUDFEES = 15L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 18L, AUDTURNOVER = 4L, RESTRUCTURE = 2L, LITIGATE = 4L, 
    AGE = 11L, AUDITLAG = 6L, UNQUALIFIED = 3L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 3L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 12L, LOGEAL = 7L, FILINGLAG = 5L, OPERATINGCFO = 14L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01    ", "-0.03*** ", "-0.05*** ", 
    "-0.08*** ", "-0.12*** ", "-0.14*** ", " 0.01*   ", " 0.02**  ", 
    " 0.07*** ", " 0.08*** ", " 0.09*** ", " 0.15*** ", " 0.16*** ", 
    " 0.24*** ", " 0.27*** ", " 0.28*** ", " 0.30*** "), class = "factor"), 
    `13` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, 
    CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, 
    INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, 
    MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 13L, EXTRAORDINARY = 2L, SEGMENT = 5L, 
    SPECIALIZED = 10L, RESTATEMENT = 2L, BIGN = 12L, GOINGCONCERN = 3L, 
    CALENDARYEAR = 11L, LNNONAUDFEES = 11L, LNAUDFEES = 10L, 
    AUDTURNOVER = 4L, RESTRUCTURE = 2L, LITIGATE = 14L, AGE = 5L, 
    AUDITLAG = 7L, UNQUALIFIED = 10L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 4L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 12L, LOGEAL = 8L, FILINGLAG = 6L, OPERATINGCFO = 9L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01    ", "-0.02**  ", "-0.02*** ", 
    "-0.04*** ", "-0.06*** ", "-0.08*** ", "-0.10*** ", " 0.01    ", 
    " 0.02*** ", " 0.03*** ", " 0.04*** ", " 0.06*** ", " 0.12*** "
    ), class = "factor"), `14` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, 
    BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 2L, 
    SEGMENT = 17L, SPECIALIZED = 11L, RESTATEMENT = 4L, BIGN = 14L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 5L, CALENDARYEAR = 4L, LNNONAUDFEES = 15L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 16L, AUDTURNOVER = 5L, RESTRUCTURE = 3L, LITIGATE = 10L, 
    AGE = 12L, AUDITLAG = 7L, UNQUALIFIED = 2L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 9L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 13L, LOGEAL = 8L, FILINGLAG = 6L, OPERATINGCFO = 12L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01    ", "-0.03*** ", "-0.04*** ", 
    "-0.07*** ", "-0.12*** ", "-0.19*** ", "-0.23*** ", " 0.01*   ", 
    " 0.06*** ", " 0.10*** ", " 0.15*** ", " 0.18*** ", " 0.22*** ", 
    " 0.31*** ", " 0.43*** ", " 0.49*** "), class = "factor"), 
    `15` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, 
    CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, 
    INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, 
    MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, SEGMENT = 11L, 
    SPECIALIZED = 11L, RESTATEMENT = 7L, BIGN = 12L, GOINGCONCERN = 7L, 
    CALENDARYEAR = 10L, LNNONAUDFEES = 13L, LNAUDFEES = 14L, 
    AUDTURNOVER = 2L, RESTRUCTURE = 7L, LITIGATE = 4L, AGE = 10L, 
    AUDITLAG = 11L, UNQUALIFIED = 6L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 10L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 5L, LOGEAL = 3L, FILINGLAG = 8L, OPERATINGCFO = 9L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01    ", "-0.02**  ", "-0.02*** ", 
    "-0.05*** ", "-0.11*** ", " 0.00    ", " 0.01*   ", " 0.02**  ", 
    " 0.02*** ", " 0.03*** ", " 0.04*** ", " 0.05*** ", " 0.06*** "
    ), class = "factor"), `16` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, 
    BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, 
    SEGMENT = 1L, SPECIALIZED = 11L, RESTATEMENT = 2L, BIGN = 13L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 6L, CALENDARYEAR = 4L, LNNONAUDFEES = 15L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 16L, AUDTURNOVER = 5L, RESTRUCTURE = 3L, LITIGATE = 8L, 
    AGE = 14L, AUDITLAG = 8L, UNQUALIFIED = 5L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 10L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 12L, LOGEAL = 9L, FILINGLAG = 7L, OPERATINGCFO = 12L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01    ", "-0.01**  ", "-0.02**  ", 
    "-0.07*** ", "-0.09*** ", "-0.11*** ", "-0.15*** ", "-0.21*** ", 
    " 0.01    ", " 0.13*** ", " 0.19*** ", " 0.20*** ", " 0.35*** ", 
    " 0.37*** ", " 0.46*** "), class = "factor"), `17` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, 
    SEGMENT = 1L, SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 3L, BIGN = 17L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 5L, CALENDARYEAR = 11L, LNNONAUDFEES = 15L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 16L, AUDTURNOVER = 7L, RESTRUCTURE = 2L, LITIGATE = 6L, 
    AGE = 13L, AUDITLAG = 9L, UNQUALIFIED = 6L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 4L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 14L, LOGEAL = 10L, FILINGLAG = 8L, OPERATINGCFO = 12L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01*   ", "-0.02**  ", "-0.03*** ", 
    "-0.04*** ", "-0.05*** ", "-0.08*** ", "-0.09*** ", "-0.13*** ", 
    "-0.15*** ", " 0.05*** ", " 0.07*** ", " 0.09*** ", " 0.13*** ", 
    " 0.19*** ", " 0.27*** ", " 0.30*** "), class = "factor"), 
    `18` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, 
    CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, 
    INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, 
    MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, SEGMENT = 1L, 
    SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 5L, GOINGCONCERN = 2L, 
    CALENDARYEAR = 9L, LNNONAUDFEES = 7L, LNAUDFEES = 7L, AUDTURNOVER = 11L, 
    RESTRUCTURE = 10L, LITIGATE = 6L, AGE = 3L, AUDITLAG = 13L, 
    UNQUALIFIED = 4L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 11L, AUDITORTENURE = 8L, 
    LOGEAL = 12L, FILINGLAG = 12L, OPERATINGCFO = 3L), .Label = c("", 
    "-0.01    ", "-0.01*   ", "-0.01**  ", "-0.02*** ", "-0.03*** ", 
    "-0.04*** ", "-0.05*** ", " 0.00    ", " 0.01    ", " 0.03*** ", 
    " 0.05*** ", " 0.06*** "), class = "factor"), `19` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, 
    SEGMENT = 1L, SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 6L, CALENDARYEAR = 12L, LNNONAUDFEES = 15L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 16L, AUDTURNOVER = 8L, RESTRUCTURE = 2L, LITIGATE = 3L, 
    AGE = 11L, AUDITLAG = 9L, UNQUALIFIED = 4L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 5L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 14L, LOGEAL = 10L, FILINGLAG = 7L, OPERATINGCFO = 13L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.02**  ", "-0.04*** ", "-0.08*** ", 
    "-0.09*** ", "-0.12*** ", "-0.24*** ", "-0.25*** ", "-0.34*** ", 
    "-0.41*** ", " 0.09*** ", " 0.10*** ", " 0.18*** ", " 0.38*** ", 
    " 0.40*** ", " 0.59*** "), class = "factor"), `20` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, 
    SEGMENT = 1L, SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 1L, CALENDARYEAR = 8L, LNNONAUDFEES = 4L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 5L, AUDTURNOVER = 10L, RESTRUCTURE = 9L, LITIGATE = 12L, 
    AGE = 3L, AUDITLAG = 14L, UNQUALIFIED = 6L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 11L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 2L, LOGEAL = 15L, FILINGLAG = 13L, OPERATINGCFO = 7L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.06*** ", "-0.07*** ", "-0.10*** ", 
    "-0.13*** ", "-0.21*** ", "-0.38*** ", " 0.02*** ", " 0.03*** ", 
    " 0.04*** ", " 0.06*** ", " 0.07*** ", " 0.12*** ", " 0.15*** ", 
    " 0.16*** "), class = "factor"), `21` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, 
    SEGMENT = 1L, SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 1L, CALENDARYEAR = 1L, LNNONAUDFEES = 9L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 10L, AUDTURNOVER = 3L, RESTRUCTURE = 8L, LITIGATE = 6L, 
    AGE = 7L, AUDITLAG = 5L, UNQUALIFIED = 3L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 3L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 9L, LOGEAL = 2L, FILINGLAG = 4L, OPERATINGCFO = 5L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01*   ", "-0.02*** ", "-0.03*** ", 
    "-0.05*** ", "-0.07*** ", "-0.12*** ", " 0.01    ", " 0.04*** ", 
    " 0.11*** "), class = "factor"), `22` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, 
    SEGMENT = 1L, SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 1L, CALENDARYEAR = 1L, LNNONAUDFEES = 1L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 13L, AUDTURNOVER = 6L, RESTRUCTURE = 2L, LITIGATE = 5L, 
    AGE = 11L, AUDITLAG = 8L, UNQUALIFIED = 4L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 3L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 12L, LOGEAL = 9L, FILINGLAG = 7L, OPERATINGCFO = 10L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.01    ", "-0.04*** ", "-0.07*** ", 
    "-0.11*** ", "-0.14*** ", "-0.20*** ", "-0.28*** ", "-0.36*** ", 
    " 0.21*** ", " 0.23*** ", " 0.25*** ", " 0.66*** "), class = "factor"), 
    `23` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, 
    CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, 
    INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, 
    MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, SEGMENT = 1L, 
    SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, GOINGCONCERN = 1L, 
    CALENDARYEAR = 1L, LNNONAUDFEES = 1L, LNAUDFEES = 1L, AUDTURNOVER = 5L, 
    RESTRUCTURE = 2L, LITIGATE = 4L, AGE = 11L, AUDITLAG = 7L, 
    UNQUALIFIED = 3L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 9L, AUDITORTENURE = 12L, 
    LOGEAL = 8L, FILINGLAG = 6L, OPERATINGCFO = 10L), .Label = c("", 
    "-0.02*** ", "-0.10*** ", "-0.12*** ", "-0.20*** ", "-0.27*** ", 
    "-0.41*** ", "-0.46*** ", " 0.00    ", " 0.24*** ", " 0.27*** ", 
    " 0.37*** "), class = "factor"), `24` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, 
    SEGMENT = 1L, SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 1L, CALENDARYEAR = 1L, LNNONAUDFEES = 1L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 1L, AUDTURNOVER = 1L, RESTRUCTURE = 5L, LITIGATE = 6L, 
    AGE = 2L, AUDITLAG = 9L, UNQUALIFIED = 6L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 7L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 4L, LOGEAL = 9L, FILINGLAG = 8L, OPERATINGCFO = 3L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.04*** ", "-0.06*** ", "-0.33*** ", 
    " 0.01    ", " 0.02*** ", " 0.08*** ", " 0.13*** ", " 0.16*** "
    ), class = "factor"), `25` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, 
    BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, 
    SEGMENT = 1L, SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 1L, CALENDARYEAR = 1L, LNNONAUDFEES = 1L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 1L, AUDTURNOVER = 1L, RESTRUCTURE = 1L, LITIGATE = 4L, 
    AGE = 4L, AUDITLAG = 4L, UNQUALIFIED = 3L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 4L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 4L, LOGEAL = 5L, FILINGLAG = 4L, OPERATINGCFO = 2L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.02**  ", "-0.02*** ", " 0.00    ", 
    " 0.01*   "), class = "factor"), `26` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, 
    SEGMENT = 1L, SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 1L, CALENDARYEAR = 1L, LNNONAUDFEES = 1L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 1L, AUDTURNOVER = 1L, RESTRUCTURE = 1L, LITIGATE = 1L, 
    AGE = 3L, AUDITLAG = 7L, UNQUALIFIED = 6L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 6L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 2L, LOGEAL = 5L, FILINGLAG = 7L, OPERATINGCFO = 4L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.05*** ", "-0.16*** ", "-0.18*** ", 
    " 0.00    ", " 0.02**  ", " 0.06*** "), class = "factor"), 
    `27` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, 
    CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, 
    INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, 
    MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, SEGMENT = 1L, 
    SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, GOINGCONCERN = 1L, 
    CALENDARYEAR = 1L, LNNONAUDFEES = 1L, LNAUDFEES = 1L, AUDTURNOVER = 1L, 
    RESTRUCTURE = 1L, LITIGATE = 1L, AGE = 1L, AUDITLAG = 4L, 
    UNQUALIFIED = 6L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 2L, AUDITORTENURE = 8L, 
    LOGEAL = 5L, FILINGLAG = 3L, OPERATINGCFO = 7L), .Label = c("", 
    "-0.04*** ", "-0.14*** ", "-0.18*** ", "-0.22*** ", " 0.00    ", 
    " 0.18*** ", " 0.37*** "), class = "factor"), `28` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, 
    SEGMENT = 1L, SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 1L, CALENDARYEAR = 1L, LNNONAUDFEES = 1L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 1L, AUDTURNOVER = 1L, RESTRUCTURE = 1L, LITIGATE = 1L, 
    AGE = 1L, AUDITLAG = 1L, UNQUALIFIED = 2L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 5L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 4L, LOGEAL = 6L, FILINGLAG = 7L, OPERATINGCFO = 3L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.08*** ", "-0.22*** ", "-0.33*** ", 
    " 0.19*** ", " 0.60*** ", " 0.86*** "), class = "factor"), 
    `29` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, 
    CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, 
    INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, 
    MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, SEGMENT = 1L, 
    SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, GOINGCONCERN = 1L, 
    CALENDARYEAR = 1L, LNNONAUDFEES = 1L, LNAUDFEES = 1L, AUDTURNOVER = 1L, 
    RESTRUCTURE = 1L, LITIGATE = 1L, AGE = 1L, AUDITLAG = 1L, 
    UNQUALIFIED = 1L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 2L, AUDITORTENURE = 6L, 
    LOGEAL = 4L, FILINGLAG = 3L, OPERATINGCFO = 5L), .Label = c("", 
    "-0.06*** ", "-0.08*** ", " 0.00    ", " 0.06*** ", " 0.13*** "
    ), class = "factor"), `30` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, 
    BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, 
    SEGMENT = 1L, SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 1L, CALENDARYEAR = 1L, LNNONAUDFEES = 1L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 1L, AUDTURNOVER = 1L, RESTRUCTURE = 1L, LITIGATE = 1L, 
    AGE = 1L, AUDITLAG = 1L, UNQUALIFIED = 1L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 1L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 3L, LOGEAL = 4L, FILINGLAG = 5L, OPERATINGCFO = 2L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.06*** ", "-0.08*** ", " 0.18*** ", 
    " 0.20*** "), class = "factor"), `31` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, 
    SEGMENT = 1L, SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 1L, CALENDARYEAR = 1L, LNNONAUDFEES = 1L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 1L, AUDTURNOVER = 1L, RESTRUCTURE = 1L, LITIGATE = 1L, 
    AGE = 1L, AUDITLAG = 1L, UNQUALIFIED = 1L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 1L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 1L, LOGEAL = 3L, FILINGLAG = 2L, OPERATINGCFO = 4L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.24*** ", "-0.27*** ", " 0.11*** "), class = "factor"), 
    `32` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, 
    CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, 
    INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, 
    MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, SEGMENT = 1L, 
    SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, GOINGCONCERN = 1L, 
    CALENDARYEAR = 1L, LNNONAUDFEES = 1L, LNAUDFEES = 1L, AUDTURNOVER = 1L, 
    RESTRUCTURE = 1L, LITIGATE = 1L, AGE = 1L, AUDITLAG = 1L, 
    UNQUALIFIED = 1L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 1L, AUDITORTENURE = 1L, 
    LOGEAL = 1L, FILINGLAG = 3L, OPERATINGCFO = 2L), .Label = c("", 
    "-0.30*** ", " 0.52*** "), class = "factor"), `33` = structure(c(DEGREE = 1L, 
    EIGENVECTOR = 1L, BETWEENNESS = 1L, CLOSENESS = 1L, OVERALLCENTRALITY = 1L, 
    LNASSETS = 1L, LEVERAGE = 1L, INVREC = 1L, LOSS = 1L, ROA = 1L, 
    ZSCORE = 1L, MERGER = 1L, MTB = 1L, FOREIGN = 1L, EXTRAORDINARY = 1L, 
    SEGMENT = 1L, SPECIALIZED = 1L, RESTATEMENT = 1L, BIGN = 1L, 
    GOINGCONCERN = 1L, CALENDARYEAR = 1L, LNNONAUDFEES = 1L, 
    LNAUDFEES = 1L, AUDTURNOVER = 1L, RESTRUCTURE = 1L, LITIGATE = 1L, 
    AGE = 1L, AUDITLAG = 1L, UNQUALIFIED = 1L, MATERIALWEAKNESS = 1L, 
    AUDITORTENURE = 1L, LOGEAL = 1L, FILINGLAG = 1L, OPERATINGCFO = 2L
    ), .Label = c("", "-0.17*** "), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-34L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Could you please show us what you have tried so far? Also, it would be helpful to share your data as `dput`.

Comment: @bttomio `dput` is given in the updated post. Thanks